# PHP attacks on sites

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, iis, web-config

I dont have any PHP files/sites installed on my server as we dont use PHP but see a lot of activity against legit sites which run on ASP .Net using C# and VB .Net.

For example the following is listed on the server against a site hosted on it

```
http://www.example.com/plus/mytag_js.php?dopost=saveedit&arrs1[]=99&arrs1[]=102
```

I've shorted the above string as its a lengthy string of arrs1[] and arrs2[] all the way through.

First thing is that the site is http**S** so i dont know how its picked up a http link? Am i missing any configuration? As testing all my theories and checking my site on an external redirect all looks good. This is what i receive:

```
http://www.example.com
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.example.com/
200 OK
```

I then decided to add the below config to the server (which in turn adds it to all sites, or should do) in IIS's main node

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                 <add input="{URL}" pattern="plus/mytag_js.php/?$" />
               </conditions>
     <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
</rule>
```

This blocked most requests but somehow the above URL still shows up in the logs. I then decided to add some "banned" keywords under Request Filtering > URL tab (Deny request). Adding arrs1[] and arrs2[] but this didnt work either.

Any other alternatives i may have missed? Unfortunately i dont have the luxury of external Web Access Filtering so i'm looking for a way on the server in IIS.

**Request Blocking Rule**

This is what i have within IIS > URL Rewrite

[image]

Comment: The server log has picked it but with the redirects (Canonical URLs, 301 redirects i assumed it would redirect to https either way). Yes i would like to "drop" or deny these requests which would indicate to me that it was an unsuccessful attempt - feel free to correct me

Comment: You mean you want to reject the requests, or just not log them? I can understand not wanting to log them, of course.

Comment: Reject these requests. By not logging them IMO i'm just masking the problem the way i see it.

Comment: What is the benefit of rejecting them? If anything, I'd think returning 403 is actually more indicative that something is there than returning the 404 that the server would presumably do by default. At the moment you only seem to have one attack source, but what if you get others over time? What if someone starts trying to request random `.aspx` files you don't have? Or `.cgi` files? It seems that you'll be fighting a losing battle.

Comment: Returning 403 is acceptable too. If they request random non existent pages then a 404 would suffice (which the sites do anyway), its when an entry is created in the server logs which i feel needs addressing but i agree not all attacks can be resolved but for now if i can block the above requests it would be lighter on the logs i have to go through

Answer (score 0):

To block all the php request you could use below URL rewrite rule at your site:

```
 <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding this as per the image now added within my original question, but it didnt work. Have i missed something or setup something incorrectly?

Comment: Use "regular expression" to match the patter instead of "wild card". [image](https://imgur.com/5mjuyTM) and you can run failed request tracing and check why this rule is not working at your site.